# How to config start services with Upstart?

Tags: upstart

Since upstart 1.5 comes with Ubuntu 12.04,
bum and sysv-rc-conf is no longer effective on it.

How can I config?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Upstart has been available in Ubuntu since Edgy (6.10). Full details are available in the manual pages on your system:

- man 5 init (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/init.5)
- man 8 init (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/init.8)
- man 7 upstart-events (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/upstart-events.7)
  (for a better formatted version, see: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific)

However, for a gentler and less terse introduction, please see the Upstart Cookbook:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/upstart_cookbook.pdf

Note that Upstart in 12.04 still continues to Support SystemV jobs, but you are encouraged to write new services using Upstart since it's a lot better! :-)

Here is some information on how to start creating a new Upstart job:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#precepts-for-creating-a-job-configuration-file

I would also highly recommend looking at the existing jobs in /etc/init/ to see how they work (some are disected in detail in the Upstart Cookbook).