# Automatically run xbmc at bootup in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, startup, xbmc

Running a fresh install of lubuntu 14.04, would like to have xbmc run at boot but I cant seem to find any system setting like that.  Any ideas where to look?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133807/how-to-config-start-services-with-upstart

Answer (score 1):

Either you try adding the command at

**/etc/rc.d/rc.local**

or

```
$ mv yourcommand.sh /etc/init.d/
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/yourcommand.sh
$ sudo update-rc.d yourcommand.sh defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

**Upstart init script for xbmc**

Create a `/etc/init/xbmc.conf` with following contents:

```
# xbmc-upstart
# starts XBMC on startup by using xinit.
# by default runs as xbmc, to change edit below.
env USER=xbmc

description     "XBMC-barebones-upstart-script"
author          "Matt Filetto"

start on (filesystem and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [016]

# tell upstart to respawn the process if abnormal exit
respawn

script
  exec su -c "xinit /usr/bin/xbmc --standalone -- -nocursor :0" $USER
end script
```

Note: `-- -nocursor` option kills all X cursor on XBMC startup and does not interfere with mouse use/operation

You may have to edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` and replace the last line that says:

`allowed_users=console` to `allowed_users=anybody`

Source: [http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Install_XBMC_for_Linux](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO%3aInstall_XBMC_for_Linux)